# 3D map view in QGIS doesn't load with many 3D models

Tags: qgis, 3d-model, 3d-map

I'm trying created 3d map view in QGIS 3.28 with 5000 points from shape-file. I want to visualize this file with 3d model from ScetchUP (obj-file size 511 Kb), but it doesn't work. Tile loading process stops. In ArcScene evrything going well with 3Ds format of objects. Maybe there is another way to visualize many objects in 3d map view in QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

I have QGIS 3.30 and can't get 3D view to work either. However, I do have a plugin called **qgis2threejs** which offers 3D viewing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).